# How can I launch a windows application from a webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, vb.net, dotnetnuke

We have a company intranet and the powers that be think it would be nice to have a collection of icons/links representing the applications that most reps use (Outlook, Excel, few other apps).

The idea would be that if the application is installed, clicking the link/icon would launch the application on the client machine.

Anyone ever had a requirement like that and been successful implementing it?

Wanted to reach out to everyone before I go back and say no. Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: I voted this up, I think it is a valid question though it may not be best practice, it may be the solution they need.

Comment: Do I assume that is for Windows OS only, or also for Mac OS ?

Comment: This will be for an internal intranet, so it will be Windows OS only at this time.

Comment: I believe the only way would be in IE with Active X.  There may be a bunch of security to jump through, but if it is for an intranet application, I don't think it should be too hard.

Comment: @Cyberdrew: Why would this not be a best practice? Isn't this a matter of UI design and app functionality? The client requested it so isn't it valid?

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: I saw this question had a -1 rating as I figure most Microsoft haters or security gurus would go nuts over launching an exe from a web browser.  Since his is an intranet request, I didn't see why it was getting voted down.  Granted, on the cloud, this would be a bad idea.

Comment: @Cyberdrew: Ok, I see. I work 99% on intranets, so this doesn't raise any flags with me (my first thought is in an intranet setting, not internet). I can see how this would be ridiculous if done "in the cloud". Yet totally valid for intranet apps.

Comment: @Richard DesLonde I agree with Cyberdrew, in intranet it's really possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make each button be a link to download a company template file for the given application. For example, the "Excel" button would download and the user should be prompted to open it with Excel.

For instance, try clicking one of the links here:

http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=template+filetype:xls

Linking to static files on the web server should be sufficient, so long as your server sends the correct MIME-Type or Content-Type.

Comment: Not an option, some of the apps don't have a file type associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to adjust browsers' security settings to allow them to follow the links, but you should be able to use URLs of the form `file:///C:\\Program Files\\Notepad.exe`  (You might prefer to use normal slashes `/` instead, as you don't have to watch out for how many copies of `\` are needed to get past quoted string interpretation in whatever you're using to design the web page(s).

Comment: But you need to make sure this only works for the intranet, not for just any website.

Comment: This makes the assumption that all users have the applications installed in the default location.

Comment: You can verify that checking the Registry, however, i don't know if you can check it on the web

Comment: You can't; you also can't verify that the applications are *installed*, so this question does presuppose a certain amount of control over the contents of client machines to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Using IE on a local intranet we have implemented this in an ActiveX control.  Josh Pearce's solution works for those types of apps with MIME types, but not all apps you may wish to open would work this way.

Comment: The IT Dept could always push a new MIME Type, I suppose.