# Window application called from web page not able to set start up application

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, windows

I am developing an windows form application.
And i also developing an asp web application.
From this web application i need to call that windows application.
And the windows application set start up application.

When i call this exe from aspx page it through error at setting start up application.

### Error

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)
```

Note whenever I execute that `exe` manually(Double clicking on exe) it works fine.
Can any one tell me what to do in this case.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237888/how-can-i-launch-a-windows-application-from-a-webpage.

Comment: I am able to call that exe from web page.My problem is that i am not able to set start up application from windows application called from web form.But when i double click on that exe that works proper.

Answer (score 0):

This is breaking fundamental web security.

Where's the exe? on the client machine that you're trying to access via a web page? Or is the exe server side? In which case, why's it a Windows form application when no one will ever see the GUI?

What's the purpose of the Windows form app? That functionality either needs to be encapsulated in a web page if it's consumer facing, or if it's server side handled some other way.

If the exe **is** installed on the client and you're trying to open it from your web page, the only way I can see how you might do this is by downloading a file with an extension that is opened by your windows form app by default for further processing etc.

Comment: No that exe is on server.And that exe registers default.aspx page as a start up application.it will through error at registering that file.

Comment: Ashish, you might want to rethink the architecture.

Comment: i am developing an auto backup utility for that i use CacheItemRemovedCallback event in global.ashx file.and i need a dummy URL to call at every Cache Item Removed.For that i need to register my aspx page at start up.And i don't need any additional working(manual working) for setting start up.

Comment: You could start the windows form using the Process.Start call however how're you going to check it has finished or to exit the Windows Forms? You might want to convert it to a simple console app that just naturally exists when finished.